# Want to put digits(decimals) to ONLY the separate percentage column values in tbl_summary. Any break down tutorial on how map works?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would want to add decimals for the percentage column only

#Separate columns
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

```
tbl <- 
  c("{n}", "{p}%") %>%         # iterate over these two statistics
  # build tbl_summary using each of the stats
  map(
    ~trial %>% 
      select(response, grade) %>% 
      tbl_summary(
        statistic = all_categorical() ~ .x,
        missing = "ifany",
    digits = list(
      all_categorical() ~ 1,
      all_continuous() ~ 0
    ),
    missing_text = "(Missing)"
      ) 
  ) %>%
  # merge the two tables together
   tbl_merge() %>%
  # some formatting to make it cute
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_header(list(stat_0_1 ~ "**n / N**", stat_0_2 ~ "**percent**"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can conditionally add a `digits=` value depending on whether we're summarizing the percentage or the counts. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl <- 
  c("{n}", "{p}%") %>%         # iterate over these two statistics
  # build tbl_summary using each of the stats
  purrr::map(
    ~trial %>% 
      select(response, grade) %>% 
      tbl_summary(
        statistic = all_categorical() ~ .x,
        missing = "ifany",
        digits = list(
          all_categorical() ~ ifelse(.x == "{p}%", 1, 0),
          all_continuous() ~ 0
        ),
        missing_text = "(Missing)"
      ) 
  ) %>%
  # merge the two tables together
  tbl_merge() %>%
  # some formatting to make it cute
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_header(list(stat_0_1 ~ "**n / N**", stat_0_2 ~ "**percent**"))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>