# Want to Organize the Count and Percentage Columns in tbl_summary using the values in the by varaible rather than having counts and percent sep tables

Tags: r, gtsummary

Hi I have a follow up question to this this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265033/want-to-put-digitsdecimals-to-only-the-separate-percentage-column-values-in-tb). Taking the code provided a step further, I have a table that I would like to get percents and counts by a variable. See code example below. When I run this, I get two tables one that has the counts and the other that has the percentages. However, I would like to have the count and % columns for each of the values in the by variable together.

```
## Example below uses data set included with the gtsummary package

library(gtsummary)
tbl <- 
  c("{n}", "{p}%") %>%         # iterate over these two statistics
  # build tbl_summary using each of the stats
  map(
    ~trial %>% 
      select(response, grade, stage) %>% 
      tbl_summary( by = stage,
        statistic = all_categorical() ~ .x,
        missing = "ifany",
        digits = list(
          all_categorical() ~ 1,
          all_continuous() ~ 0
        ),
        missing_text = "(Missing)"
      ) 
  ) %>%
  # merge the two tables together
  tbl_merge()
```

My current work around is to add a filter for each value in the by variable and merge those tables together.

Wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: does the default behavior do what you want : https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html

Comment: Generally yes, but I want the counts and percents to be in different columns for my publication purposes. The default behavior puts both into a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `map2()` from `purrr` to loop over both the by variable (now in `filter()`) and statistic (n and percent). Then merge them together. Order matters for the two vector inputs.

```
library(gtsummary)

 trial <- mutate(trial, stage = as.character(stage))
  # iterate over these two statistics
  # build tbl_summary using each of the stats
  map2(list("T1", "T1", "T2","T2"),
       list("{n}", "{p}%","{n}", "{p}%"),
       
    ~trial %>% 
      filter(stage == .x) %>% 
      select(response, grade, stage) %>% 
      tbl_summary( by = stage,
                   statistic = all_categorical() ~ .y,
                   missing = "ifany",
                   digits = list(
                     all_categorical() ~ 1,
                     all_continuous() ~ 0
                   ),
                   missing_text = "(Missing)" ) )  %>% 
    tbl_merge()
```

[image]